# Can't get help for SQL commands in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

I have read another entries about this topic, but none of them works for me.

I'm runnign SQL*Plus from bash shell in Linux. The SQL*Plus version is:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

I've tried to enable the help facility as per this FAQ:
[http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#How_does_one_enable_the_SQL.2APlus_HELP_facility.3F](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ#How_does_one_enable_the_SQL.2APlus_HELP_facility.3F)

But I got an error importing the help scripts:

```
DROP VIEW HELP_TEMP_VIEW
*
ERROR en línea 1:
ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
```

Now, if I try to get the help for the SELECT command, I get a message telling me the there's no help available for this subject:

```
SQL> help select
SP2-0172: No se ha encontrado la ayuda que coincida con este tema.
```

If I perform "help index" to show what topics are covered by the built-in help, it seems that only SQL*Plus commands are covered, but none of the SQL sentences:

```
SQL> help index
Enter Help [topic] for help.

 @             COPY         PAUSE                    SHUTDOWN
 @@            DEFINE       PRINT                    SPOOL
 /             DEL          PROMPT                   SQLPLUS
 ACCEPT        DESCRIBE     QUIT                     START
 APPEND        DISCONNECT   RECOVER                  STARTUP
 ARCHIVE LOG   EDIT         REMARK                   STORE
 ATTRIBUTE     EXECUTE      REPFOOTER                TIMING
 BREAK         EXIT         REPHEADER                TTITLE
 BTITLE        GET          RESERVED WORDS (SQL)     UNDEFINE
 CHANGE        HELP         RESERVED WORDS (PL/SQL)  VARIABLE
 CLEAR         HOST         RUN                      WHENEVER OSERROR
 COLUMN        INPUT        SAVE                     WHENEVER SQLERROR
 COMPUTE       LIST         SET                      XQUERY
 CONNECT       PASSWORD     SHOW
```

It would be great to get help for SQL commands, as in the mysql client. Any help is more than welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've peeked into the scripts and the ORA-00942 is normally expected and does not break anything.

This works as designed. Oracle just didn't supply HELP for SELECT, UPDATE, CREATE, etc, presumably because they would be huge pages. The internal sqlplus commands that you've seen with `HELP INDEX` are all you can expect.

The help contents are in the file `helpus.sql` in open text. I've tried to google for something similar from any old version but to no avail. If you really wish to have some customized HELP contents, I think you are on your own to write your own script along the lines of helpus.sql and to add the topics as you wish.

```
SQL> alter session set current_schema=system ;
SQL> INSERT INTO HELP VALUES ('TEST123', 1, 'Just testing...' ) ;
SQL> commit;
SQL> help test123
Just testing...
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. In that case, I guess there should be help scripts created by other users? I'll try to look for them.

Comment: @cortezthekiller I've tried to google for such user-made scripts, but I've found none.